# read array 2 dimensions in another way C++

Tags: c++

after reading inputs to an array:

```
std::vector<unsigned char *> inputs(elements);
```

the "`inputs`" is a 2 dimensional array: `inputs[3][2]`, then reading this array out, the values are:

```
inputs[0][0]=1
inputs[0][1]=2
inputs[1][0]=3
inputs[1][1]=4
inputs[2][0]=5
inputs[2][1]=6
```

I would like to read this 2-dimensional array into one dimensional array:

```
int counter=0;
int * allElements = new int[6];

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
   {
      allElements[counter++] = (int)inputs[i][j];
   }
```

That is a traditional way of reading all of the elements into one dimensional array and I believe if I read the elements of "`allElements`" this way:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
   printf("%d ", allElements[i]);
```

and it should be: `1 2 3 4 5 6`

However, I would like to read all elements of two dimensional array into the 1 dimensional array such that when I do it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
   printf("%d ", allElements[i]);
```

It should be: `1 3 5 2 4 6`

In the words, reading all of the first elements of 2 dimensional arrays first.

How can I achieve this way?

Comment: Why are you using `unsigned char *` instead of `vector<int>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is reverse the order of the loops:

```
int counter=0;
int * allElements = new int[6];

for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
      allElements[counter++] = (int)inputs[i][j];
   }
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Just swap your `i` and `j` loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
   {
      allElements[counter++] = (int)inputs[j][i];
   }
```