# read in array into another array C++

Tags: c++

after reading inputs to an array:

```
int * inputs;
```

the "`inputs`" is 1 dimensional array: `inputs[6]`, then reading this array out, the values are:

```
inputs[0]=1
inputs[1]=2
inputs[2]=3
inputs[3]=4
inputs[4]=5
inputs[5]=6
```

I would like to read this array into another one dimensional array:

```
int counter=0;
int * allElements = new int[6];

for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
      allElements[counter++] = inputs[i];
}
```

That is a traditional way of reading all of the elements into one dimensional array and I believe if I read the elements of "`allElements`" this way:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
   printf("%d ", allElements[i]);
```

and it should be: `1 2 3 4 5 6`

However, I would like to read all elements of that array into the 1 dimensional array such that when I do it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
   printf("%d ", allElements[i]);
```

It should be: `1 3 5 2 4 6`

How can I achieve this way?

Comment: You could write a function which calculates the index of allElements from the index of inputs.

Comment: I don't think any of this deserves to be called "C++"... why are you using pointers and `new`? Use the standard library containers for arrays (`vector` or `array`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [read array 2 dimensions in another way C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129084/read-array-2-dimensions-in-another-way-c)

Comment: @KerrekSB probably, some codes I wrote it in C# way, but I would like to do it in C++

Comment: @aschepler no, they are two different questions. I would like to know both ways

Comment: @Kerrek 'new' is a C++ operator.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: "C++" is as much about idiom as it is about language features.

Comment: I think this is suppose to be a logic problem more than a C++ problem.

Comment: Are you sorting by value or location?

Comment: @Tomalak ... and yet C++ still includes pointers and new.  In fact, for many years that was the only option in C++.  So saying that pointers-and-new don't deserve to be called C++ is incorrect; it may be old-school C++ but it is still C++.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: That was twenty years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    allElements[i] = inputs[2*(i%3) + (i/3)];
}
```

Imagine `inputs` is a two-dimension array, of 3x2, then i%3 is one coordinate and i/3 the other. Just transpose it into a 2x3 matrix, and done!

Comment: @JoeMcGrath Right, I made it backwards. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

```
int * allElements = new int[6];

for(int i=0; i<6; i+=2)
{
    allElements[i/2] = inputs[i];
    allElements[3+i/2] = inputs[i+1];
}
```

Comment: Might as well unroll it if it is going to be for only 1 case.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int size =6;
int inputs[size]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int allElements[size];

...

  if (size % 2)
  {
      int middle=(size/2) +1;
      for(int i=0; i<size; i+=2)
      {   
          allElements[i/2] = inputs[i];
          if (i < size-2)
            allElements[middle+i/2] = inputs[i+1];          
      }      

  }
  else
  {
    int middle=size/2;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i+=2)
    { 
      allElements[i/2] = inputs[i];
      allElements[middle+i/2] = inputs[i+1];
    }      
  }
```

Logic can definitely be simplified. Just first attempt and left it alone.

If want it to work for the 1 case

```
allElements[0]=inputs[0];      
allElements[1]=inputs[2];
allElements[2]=inputs[4];
allElements[3]=inputs[1];
allElements[4]=inputs[3];
allElements[5]=inputs[5];
```